# Regex: Only 1 space but not at the start, no numbers/special characters, any string before or after space needs to have at least 2 alphabetic chars

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to create a function which will check that if a string contains a number, a special character or a double space, but I feel that my way of writing it is not right and it's also not giving the desired result.

Requirements :

**1. No space should to be allowed in beginning.**

**2. No special character allowed but hyphen (-), and this is done already**

**3. If a string has one space anywhere, a second space is not allowed**

**Example:
wd x d w**

This should be not allowed.

What actually happens here is, IF I am inserting a space after a string, it's not allowing more than one space but if I am returning somewhere between the string and inserting a space there, then it's allowing the space.

**4. Before or after space, at least 2 alphabetic characters need to be there.**

This should be not allowed:

**A kumar**

Please help me out.

```js
 $('#atul').on('input', function(evt) {
        var inputValue = $("#atul").val();
        var withoutSpclChar = new RegExp(/^[\w| |_-]+$/);
        if (!inputValue.match(withoutSpclChar)) {
            var newInputWithHas = $("#atul").val();
            var newInputWithoutHas = newInputWithHas.substring(0, newInputWithHas.length - 1);
            return $("#atul").val(newInputWithoutHas);
        }
        if ((inputValue.match(new RegExp(" ", "g")) || []).length > 1) {
            var newInputValue = $("#atul").val();
            var noDoubleSpace = newInputValue.replace(/  +/g, '');
            var NoSpaceinEnd = noDoubleSpace.replace(/ $/, "");
            return $("#atul").val(NoSpaceinEnd);
        }
        if(/\d/.test(inputValue)) {
          console.log("it has number");
          var noNumber = inputValue.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
          return $("#atul").val(noNumber);
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="" id="atul" name="">
```

Comment: Only alphabets or also numbers you want??

Comment: no numbers needed, that's what I achieved , its not allowing me to enter numbers. this condition is working

Comment: oaky. i will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

I have regex for you if it helps you. Which will match your all criterias

```
^[a-zA-Z-]{2,}\s?([a-zA-Z-]{2,})?$
```

Comment: its not working at all, or may be I am doing it wrong.

Comment: this will not allow number now. will add it soon

Comment: can you try now?

Comment: https://codepen.io/atulraj89/pen/xvbENm
 Check this, its not working as expected, I am able to insert more than 1 space, and I am able to insert space before anything,

Comment: How?? matches all criteria.

Comment: I have given the codepen link above, you can check yourself

Comment: tried all criterias. which doesnt match. can you suggest??

Comment: I am able to enter *dc   asc asc*

may be I am doing something wrong, as I am new to regex, Can you look into my code on codepen link and correct me where I am making mistake, Thanks in advance

Comment: your code is popping alert on match the criteria. "dc asc asc" will not giving any alert so it means it doesnt match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196686/discussion-between-atul-and-r-v).

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** here is solution for you answer:
https://jsfiddle.net/6dzf8rw7/1/

```
        $('#atul').on('input', function(evt) {

        var inputValue = $("#atul").val();
        inputValue = inputValue.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "");
        $("#atul").val(inputValue);

        var withoutSpclChar = new RegExp(/^[\w| |_-]+$/);
        if (!inputValue.match(withoutSpclChar)) {
            var newInputWithHas = $("#atul").val();
            var newInputWithoutHas = newInputWithHas.substring(0, newInputWithHas.length - 1);
            return $("#atul").val(newInputWithoutHas);
        }
        if (inputValue.match(/\s+/g)) {
           $("#atul").val(spaceHandle(inputValue))
        }

        if ((inputValue.match(new RegExp(" ", "g")) || []).length > 1) {
            console.log();
            $("#atul").val(spaceHandle(inputValue))
            var newInputValue = $("#atul").val();
            var noDoubleSpace = newInputValue.replace(/  +/g, '');
            var NoSpaceinEnd = noDoubleSpace.replace(/ $/, "");
            return $("#atul").val(NoSpaceinEnd);
        }
        if(/\d/.test(inputValue)) {
          console.log("it has number");
          var noNumber = inputValue.replace(/[0-9]/g, '');
           return $("#atul").val(noNumber);
        }
    });

function spaceHandle(s) {
console.log(s);
    var replaced = s.split(' ');
    console.log(replaced);
    var final_string = '';
    $.each(replaced,function(index,value){
      if(index === 0 && value.length > 1){
       final_string = final_string+value+' ';
      }else{
        final_string = final_string+value;
      }
     })
    console.log(final_string);

    return final_string;
}
```

Comment: Hi Rishab, 

Thanks for your quick responce, only one condition its not matching, If i am putting only single alphabet in the beginning then its allowing it to be there.

Like i put **A kumar** so It should not allow it. as it has only one char before space, You can think it like first name need to be at least 2 char long

Comment: Okay will provide you solution for same

Comment: I have updated my answer check it and mark this answer correct!

Comment: I have cheeked and one more thing occurred , its allowing Special char like & % #, these should not allowed.